# Почему передается неправильное значение аргументов в поток?

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Уважаемые!
Пишу для себя, начал немного разбираться в потоках.
возникла ошибка неправильного количества передаваемых аргументов.
На мой взгляд, всё выглядит логично, но как решить данную проблему, не очень могу понять а именно:
есть функция сканирования СОМ портов.

```py
def scan_ttyusb():
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    result = ""
    for text in ports:
        if 'Pcui' in text[1]:
            txt = text[0]
            result = result + txt + ','
            device_port = result

    return device_port.split(",")
```

Она возвращает мне строку примерно такого вида:

```
[/dev/ttyUSB7],[/dev/ttyUSB2]
```

далее, я объявляю поток и передаю ему нужные аргументы

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    plate1 = scan_ttyusb()[0]
    print(plate1 + " Это первая плата")
    plate2 = scan_ttyusb()[1]
    print(plate2 + " Это вторая плата")
    thread1 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=plate1)
    thread2 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=plate2)

    start = time.time()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    end = time.time()
    print("Время работы потока 1: " + time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(end - start)))
    thread2.join()
    end2 = time.time()
    print("Время работы потока 2: " + time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(end2 - start)))
```

на что получаю ошибку в виде:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: runing_scan() takes 1 positional argument but 12 were given
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: runing_scan() takes 1 positional argument but 12 were given
```

то есть логически я понимаю, что
`/dev/ttyUSB2` - 12 символов
и
`/dev/ttyUSB7` - 12 символов.

отсюда возникает вопрос, как правильно передать значение.

Если вызывать функцию ручками:

```
runing_scan(plate1)
```

то всё отлично работает

Вопрос конечно легкий и тупой, но я не знаю как его решить.

Буду очень признателен, за разъяснение моей ошибки или хотя бы подсказки в какую сторону рыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего поможет передача аргументов в виде списка из одного элемента:

```
    thread1 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate1])
    thread2 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate2])
```

Просто тут на вход ожидается кортеж или список аргументов и когда вы передаёте строку, то она итерируется и передаётся список символов этой строки в качестве аргументов. А если передать список или кортеж, то всё будет нормально - аргументы возьмутся из этого списка.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, я был прав на счёт простого и тупого вопроса.

Comment: @Gruvi Обычно не бывает тупых вопросов, бывает просто мало знаний. Вопрос у вас хорошо оформлен, это главное )